# Date picker for different calendar

Tags: c#, wpf

I am using wpf and I want to create a new type of calendar for datepicker because Ethiopian calendar has different form the normal Gorigoran calendar. It has 13 months in a year with 12 months that has 30 days and the last month has 5 days for three years and 6 days for each leap year. How to solve this?

Comment: I don't know about the date picker part, but my [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org) supports the Coptic calendar, which sounds like it's at least broadly the same, if that's any use...

Comment: Creating your own DateTime class wouldn't be that hard, but a user control for it could be some very difficult stuff.